# how to add seconds to string time stamp (yyyy-mm-ddTH:i:s+tz) in java

Tags: java, date, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have a String variable called time is **2016-11-30T00:06:42+05:30**

and a duration **32700** i.e **545** minutes.

I want to add duration to above string time stamp and need to calculate start time and end time.

So i want to get StartTime:**00:06** and EndTime:**09:05**.

I tried this but doesn't work

```
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

      Date date = sdf.parse(startTime.toString());
      Timestamp ts_now = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
      System.out.println(">>>>>>"+date);
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTimeInMillis(ts_now.getTime());
      cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(Value.toString()));
      Timestamp later = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
      System.out.println(">>>>>>"+later);
```

I tried with **X ,Z** but got error like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-11-30T00:06:42+05:30"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at oneraise.radis.thread.mavenproject1.ParseJson.main(ParseJson.java:48)
```

I am new to java can anybody help me

Thanks

Comment: I am unable to parse that string using SimpleDateFormat (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z')

Comment: @TilakMadichetti Now can you help?

Comment: what about Value here  ?

Comment: Value already highlighted in bold 2016-11-30T00:06:42+05:30

Comment: It seems to me that `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is as made for this task. It would probably require you to switch to the new Java date and time classes, like `LocalTime`, for instance. A switch I don’t think you’ll regret, though.

Comment: If you prefer to stick with `SimpleDateFormat`, you may use `X` to accept an ISO 8601 time zone, which `+05:30` should match.

Comment: i just need output i don't need to have SimpleDateFormat , any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-11-30T00:06:42+05:30" )
    .plus( Duration.ofSeconds( 32_700L ) )
```

## Details

Avoid the troublesome and confusing date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and `Calendar`, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input string complies with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Such strings can be directly parsed by java.time classes with no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Parse as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-11-30T00:06:42+05:30" );
```

The `ZonedDateTime` class used in another Answer is inappropriate here. This input string contains only an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), not a full time zone such as [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata). So `OffsetDateTime` is the class to use here.

The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class handles your span of time, a count of seconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 32_700L );
```

Add to your date-time object.

```
OffsetDateTime odtLater = odt.plus( d );
```

Tip: To view the `OffsetDateTime` value in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

### Database

For database access, your JDBC 4.2 compliant driver may be able to work with java.time objects via the get/setObject methods.

If so, no need to use the old `java.sql.Timestamp` class or its siblings.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt );
```

If not, use the new conversion methods added to the old date-lime classes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( odt.toInstant() );
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine when it comes to the Java 8 classes, thanks for the explanation. If the OP needs a `java.sql.Timestamp`, should s/he then do `new Timestamp(odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli())`?

Comment: @OleV.V. Easier to call the new conversion methods added to the old classes. See the added "Database" section at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the format for the string you have given

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date;
    try
    {
```

Here I've parsed the string you have given.  If you want the current time, use date = new Date();

```
        date = sdf.parse("2016-11-30T00:06:42+05:30");
        System.out.println(date);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
```

Here I've added your interval

```
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 32700);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
        String output = outputFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(output);
        String output2 = outputFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(output2);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the output.  I'm in a different timezone.

Tue Nov 29 13:06:42 CST 2016

Tue Nov 29 22:11:42 CST 2016

13:06

22:11

Comment: Thanks, This is perfect...but its not giving me added second result i.e 00:06+545 minutes=09:05

Comment: That's because if you add 545 minutes to 00:06 it is not 09:05, it is 09:11.  545 minutes is 9 hours and 5 minutes.  You would have to add 539 minutes to get 09:05.

Comment: sry for typo, now i got solution, The text for SimpleDateFormat would have "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" ,then its working.

Answer (score 1):

If in your code I change the initialization of the date format to:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

— and I set my computer’s time zone to IST, I get the following output:

```
>>>>>>Wed Nov 30 00:06:42 IST 2016
>>>>>>2016-11-30 09:11:42.0
```

Alternatively you may use the Java 8 time classes, but convert to good old `Timestamp` if this is what you need. Edit: I am thankful to Basil Bourque for correctly pointing out that `OffsetDateTime` is the class to use, and for the method for converting to timestamp. See his answer for the full explanation.

```
    Instant laterInstant = OffsetDateTime.parse(startTime.toString())
            .plusSeconds(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()))
            .toInstant();
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(laterInstant);
    System.out.println(ts);
```

This prints:

```
2016-11-30 09:11:42.0
```

I believe the above does what you want.